# C++ double to long long

Tags: c++, floating-point, double, floating-point-conversion

If i write code in c++:

```
long long d = 999999998.9999999994;
cout<<d;
```

I get output: `999999999` (rounding up)

But output of this code:

```
long long d = 999999998.9999994994;
cout<<d;
```

is `999999998` (rounding down)

Is it something to do with precision. Is there any way i can change precision. `floor()` function also gives the same output.

I also noticed that if i assign value `8.9999994994` or `8.9999999994` to `d`(above variable). Output is `8`.

Comment: You can explicitly add 0.5 and cast double to long long.

Comment: C++11 support?  User defined literals could help.

Comment: @OleksandrVerhun You can do this, but if your goal is to round the floating-point number to the nearest integer, you shouldn't do this. https://www.frama-c.com/floating-point/2013/05/02/Harder-than-it-looks-rounding-float-to-nearest-integer-part-1.html

Comment: @OleksandrVerhun If you really have to round to nearest integer, please use lrint() family of functions. They are POSIX and C99, supported by glibc and Visual Studio 2013. http://linux.die.net/man/3/lrint

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`999999998.9999999994` is not exactly representable in `double`, so the actual value is one of the two representable numbers on either side of `999999998.9999999994` - either `999999998.99999988079071044921875` or `999999999` (assuming IEEE-754 `binary64` format), selected in an implementation-defined manner. Most systems will by default round to nearest, producing `999999999`.

The net result is that on those systems when you write `999999998.9999999994` it ends up having the exact same effect as writing `999999999.0`. Hence the subsequent conversion yields `999999999` - the conversion from a floating point number to an integer always truncates, but here there is nothing to truncate.

With `999999998.9999994994`, the closest representable numbers are `999999998.999999523162841796875` and  `999999998.99999940395355224609375`. Either one produces `999999998` after truncation. Similarly, with `8.9999999994`, the closest representable numbers are `8.999999999399999950355777400545775890350341796875` and `8.9999999994000017267126168007962405681610107421875`, and either one will produce `8` after truncation.

Answer (score 4):

```
long long d = 999999998.9999999994;
```

The closest value to `999999998.9999999994` that `double` can represent is `999999999.0` - remember that floating points have finite precision ;).
Therefore, truncating the decimal places yields `999999999`, and thats what is saved in `d`.

Using a literal with `L`-suffix does indeed lead to `999999998` being saved in `d` - `long double` has a higher precision.

```
long long d = 999999998.9999994994;
```

The closest value to `999999998.9999994994` that `double` can represent is actually below `999999999` - approximately `999999998.999999523` on my machine. Truncating the decimal places subsequently yields `999999998`, and that is stored in `d`.